# Is there a way to avoid show the alt of an image while angular is loading?

Tags: angularjs, image

So I am using angularjs and I am loading images with ng-src but for a second I can see the alt of the image like this

[image alt while loading the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9hPI.png)

is there any way that I can avoid it?

Comment: If you add the `ng-cloak` directive to the element does that prevent it from showing?

Comment: Try not putting the alt attribute (i.e. leave alt="") until angularjs is loaded

Comment: or set href to a static default image and it should be replaced with your values once loaded

Answer (score 2):

Out of the box not, unfortunately.
But you can create a custom directive.

**JS**

```
app.directive('ngAlt', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      if (attrs.ngAlt) {
        elem.on('load', function (event) {
          elem[0].setAttribute("alt", attrs.ngAlt);
        });
      }
    }
  };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img ng-src="path_to_your_image.jpg" ng-alt="your alt text" />
```

**In action**
https://plnkr.co/edit/3TMlauvEw5vqMqRrNcox